# Using XSLT to remove/replace invalid characters

Tags: xslt, replace

I am looking for a way to test a given element in the source XML and remove characters that are not valid. Basically, I have a list of allowed characters and need a way to replace any not in that list. Can this be done in XSLT?

To clarify: I am using XSLT to process a Valid and Complete source XML file so that it can be sent to a consuming system.

The consuming system defines what characters are allowed in certain elements and will reject the XML payload if it contains characters that are not valid. For example: they have provided the following "rule" for valid characters for a specific field:

```
([0-9a-zA-Z/\-\?:\(\)\.,'\+ \r\n]+)
```

So what I am looking to do is replace any character that does not match the rule above with null. Right now the main cause of rejection is underscores in the field. I know I can use replace to remove that character but I was hoping to define a single replace rule that would replace any character that is not in the above rule.

Comment: The simple answer is "maybe" depending on what you call "invalid".  For a more detailed answer you will need to provide more concrete details about what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please add  a [mcve] and state which version of XSLT you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace()` as hinted above. Using your regular expression for valid characters, you could try this:

```
replace($string,"[^0-9a-zA-Z/\-\?:\(\)\.,'\+ \r\n]+","")
```

You can see that your regular expression is almost as it was, except that `^` has been added to turn the set of valid characters to its complement.

Comment: Harikoo and @ocrdu many thanks.  Both options work unfortunately it appears that XSL 2 is not available to me in the application I am using so I resorted to translate.  Thanks both for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `translate()` or `replace()` (the latter is XSLT2 only), I suppose, but if the characters are invalid in the sense that the XML is no longer well-formed, then you can't use XSLT, as it requires at least a well-formed XML document.

Using `translate()`, removing all characters *except* those specified in a list goes like this:

```xml
translate($string, translate($string,'0123456789',''),'')
```

The above will remove everything *not* in the set 0123456789.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64587042/12570891) shows a way of doing it using `replace()` and a regular expression.

If you have control over whatever generates the XML, I would look there for a solution.

Comment: By invalid the consuming service only permits certain characters for elements and will reject the payload if the field contains what that service deems to be invalid (e.g. the _ character is not permitted).  The source XML is well formed and valid.